# Primefaces Watermark: hide placeholder on click

Tags: javascript, css, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

The current behavior of the Primefaces Watermark component is to hide the placeholder text if the input field is not empty. Is there any way to achieve this behavior if someone clicks on the input field? Any suggestion would be very helpful.

Comment: Why -2? Is it a wrong question?

Comment: Likely because it's not an understandable Java question. It's more a HTML/CSS/JS matter. I removed the irrelvant `[java]` tag as it would not attract the right folks for the matter anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It's an ugly Javascript hack but the following works:

`onclick="$(this).attr('placeholder', '');"`

when placed on the input element.